# How to convert Boost thread pool from fifo to priority?

Tags: c++, boost, threadpool, sample, thread-priority

I am working on a Boost thread pool.

I have a structure like this:

```
class SimThreadPool
{
    static SimThreadPool* getInstance();

   boost::threadpool::prio_pool& getThreadPool() { return mThreadPool; }

    simTerrain::SimThreadPool::SimThreadPool()
    : mThreadPool(boost::threadpool::fifo_pool(1))
    {

    }

    boost::threadpool::prio_pool mThreadPool;
}
```

When I need a thread, I call it like this:

```
  SimThreadPool::getInstance()->getThreadPool().schedule(MyThread());
```

and it works.

The question is: How can I convert this thread pool from fifo to priority?

I changed all my `fifo\_pool` to **`prio\_pool`**, but I could not manage this - it didn't work. I got some errors.

How can I use a `prio_pool` in this situation?

I think I have to use `prio_task_func` instead of a class, but I want to re-use my existing algorithms for this purpose.

Comment: Please supply the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to declare mThreadPool as:

```
boost::threadpool::scoped_pool<boost::threadpool::prio_pool, 0> mThreadPool;
```

before you use `prio_task_func` in your class.

Have you looked at http://sourceforge.net/projects/threadpool/ ?